# Which Perl module would you recommend for JSON manipulation?

Tags: json, perl, cpan, perl-module

As usual, I'm happy to deal with CPAN because it got all we need. As usual, I'm lost because there is plenty of stuff.

I can find the core [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) one by myself, and feel enthusiastic by a [`JSON::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/DAVIDO/JSON-Tiny-0.22/lib/JSON/Tiny.pod) other.

My needs are very simple (parsing stuffs from the [Open Library API](http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=perl%20modules)) and, maybe someday, expose our own data.

Is there any other modules that you like for this task?

Comment: JSON::Tiny's use case is situations where you need a JSON implementation that is lightweight and that doesn't require a compiler as XS does. It's good for bundling too. If you need a pure-Perl JSON package, it's for you. If you can afford the XS toolchain, JSON::XS is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions @DavidO, I've finally used  JSON::XS and it's great and simple to use.

Comment: Cpanel::JSON::XS is fastest and most up-to-date See the Comparing the speed of JSON decoders article http://perlmaven.com/comparing-the-speed-of-json-decoders

Comment: @szagab The URL you give actually doesn't say it's the fastest. Also, the Cpanel fork doesn't contain any fixes, only some dirty hacks that can bite you later.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) module works like a champ, but if you need a faster parser, use this one: [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::XS), which requires a native compilation.

Note that JSON version 2.0 and above is merely a front end for JSON::XS (if installed) or JSON::PP (fallback).

Comment: JSON will use JSON::XS by default if both are installed.

Comment: @Sebf, Feel free to add a call to `sleep` if you think it's too fast.

Comment: 25 years of experience in the business says JSON. 24-year-old script kiddies may say "JSON::XS" --- don't listen to them.

Comment: "Am I so out of touch? No, it is the children who are wrong." - Seymour Skinner

Comment: Note that `JSON::PP` is a core module nowadays.

Comment: (Sorry for the edit; I thought I was editing my own answer. Rolled back)

Answer (score 12):

[*Update: I now recommend [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS) over JSON::XS. Cpanel::JSON::XS is a better maintained version of JSON::XS.*]

I always use [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::XS). Complete, robust, proven, fast*, easy to use, and even a bit of flexibility if you need it.

It's probably the most used JSON parser, though most access it through [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) (but doing so risks using slower [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::PP) instead).

* — "An order of magnitude" faster than JSON::Tiny, according to [JSON::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::Tiny)'s docs.

Comment: And if you encounter one of the many bugs in JSON::XS, you might want to fallback to Cpanel::JSON::XS, which got them fixed. Or use JSON::Any or JSON::MaybeXS, which picks the best one.

Comment: Calling JSON::XS "actively maintained" might be a long shot, and you might very alone with this opinion. He refuses to use a bugtracker because "RT sucks", so you cannot see the errors other people are reporting, which I have to fix then for our fork. Most of these errors are ignored for non-technical reasons.
RT sucks, yes, I agree, so I use a better tracker. But this is no excuse to ignore most error reports.

Comment: @rurban, I was thinking of Text::CSV_XS. I don't know about JSON::XS's maintenance history. The author of JSON::XS is indeed a pain to deal with. (For eaxmple, he refuses to to use CPAN-RT, but doesn't provide an alternate means of reporting in the META files, so CPAN says to use CPAN-RT...)

Comment: JSON::XS is quite clearly actively maintained. @rurban: You should stop spreading FUD and maybe push your cpanel module a bit less aggressively, given that it is mostly dirty hacks.

Answer (score 11):

Since you say that you are getting the data from an online source, you might consider the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) tool suite. In that way you can [get the data](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent), [parse it](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/JSON) and maybe even use [JSON pointers](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/JSON/Pointer) to extract info.

Basic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $data = $ua->get('http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=perl%20modules')
              ->res
              ->json;
```

With url constructor and JSON pointer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Mojo::URL;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $url = Mojo::URL->new('http://openlibrary.org/search.json')
                   ->query( title => 'perl modules' );

say $ua->get($url)
       ->res
       ->json('/docs/0/title_suggest');
```

Note that the `json` method on the response object either returns the whole parsed data structure or can take a pointer string (as in the second example) to return just a subset to get you going quickly. Enjoy.

Comment: Seems very interesting and simple to use. I don't mention we were using Catalyst but as far as I know their is no equivalent for it.

Comment: Mojolicious was actually written by the author of Catalyst, originally as its replacement. Now it is commonly accepted that the two are distinct projects. Many would claim that its silly to use Mojolicious in a Catalyst project, but since it is so light, I see no reason not to personally. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) - Uses Cpanel::JSON::XS with a fallback to JSON::XS and JSON::PP.

Cpanel::JSON::XS has [improvements](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS#cPanel-fork) over JSON::XS, so JSON::MaybeXS makes your code nice and portable.

Usually I would look to [Task::Kensho](https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho) if I'm not sure of which module to use for a specific situation, though they don't have JSON at the moment, I've reported it to them!

Comment: Nice you report it to Task::Kensho ! As there is some modules about XML, JSON seems important too.

Comment: Task::Kensho is managed on [github](https://github.com/EnlightenedPerlOrganisation/task-kensho) suggestions in the form of tickets (or better Pull Requests!) are always welcome. Everything in TK goes through a discussion and review process that's based out of `#epo-ec` on `irc.perl.org`.

Answer (score 5):

I've started using [Mojo::JSON](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::JSON) every chance I get. The [Mojolicious](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious) is easy to install and as [Joel Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468327/joel-berger) showed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597159/2766176), it comes with much more.

Answer (score 2):

[JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-2.33/XS.pm) would be  a good module.