# Windows Batch - Pretty Print JSON per Script

Tags: json, batch-file, command-line, scripting

I have multiple JSON-files on a server, which can only run batch-scripts or command-line tools. The JSON files all aren't formatted properly, meaning there are no tab-spaces at the beginning of lines.

Is there a way, to write a batch-script or run a command-line tool to format the files, so they are normal again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will definitely need an external tool for that. I'm using the [command-line JSON processor `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) - just pass it the Identity filter `.` and it will pretty print the JSON it's been given as input.

*Update:* Corrected syntax (where did that come from?), Sorry @Delfic and @Sonata. Even though the empty filter `""` from my original answer works, I changed the filter like @Wolf said, as it is indeed mentioned in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) as the "absolute simplest filter".

Example:

```
ECHO { "att1": 1, "att2": 2 } | jq .
```

Output:

```
{
  "att1": 1,
  "att2": 2
}
```

If you want to process JSON input directly from the shell, you can also use null input `-n`:

```
jq -n "{ "att1" : 1, "att2" : 2 }"
```

To process a file, do:

```
jq . dirty.json
```

...or, if you're so inclined:

```
TYPE dirty.json | jq .
```

Comment: The filter `.` is recommended in the `jq` documentation, it also does the prettifying implicitly. This option is much easier to provide in Windows command lines.

Comment: This does not work. Also with larger file sizes jq just crashes.

Comment: @zb226 didn't work for me either. The output is just a single line with JSON. This does work however: `ECHO {"att1": 1, "att2": 2 } | jq "."`

Comment: +1 Excellent! If you use [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/), jq is available in the main bucket. It installs in seconds with `scoop install jq`.

Comment: it's so slow ((   1-2 seconds for my json with 40 lines

Comment: @user2602807 Can't confirm. `jq` will process the [Penn historic dataset](http://www.penn.museum/collections/assets/data/historic-json-latest.zip), which is just under 1.5MB, in 0.3s on my dated machine. Note that outputting to the console may be very slow on Windows, depending on the version - try redirecting into a file by appending `> pretty.json` to the command.

Answer (score 13):

Super quick way to do it if you have python installed is by typing following in the command prompt or powershell:

```
type dirty.json | python -m json.tool > pretty.json
```

where *dirty.json* is minified or unreadable json and *pretty.json* is pretty one. you can even put it in a batch file to run it by passing an argument. Its very fast in processing.

**Explanation:**
type is writing the file content to the console but its piped so it is being sent to python's module json.tool and then '>' writes the output into a file called 'pretty.json'. Try without the `> pretty.json` to see the output in the console.

Comment: This doesn't work reliably whereas [`jq` does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33123564/2932052). I failed when processing a Pandoc output. Right in the first lines, I observed data loss. So this suggestion is **counterproductive** when you wish to just format JSON.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the output you tried formating? I dont think there will be data loss with the approach I mentioned.

Comment: I converted a Markdown document into JSON via Pandoc. When reformatting, the python json.tool removed the Pandoc meta data.

Comment: I like this answer: I prefer using python to installing a dedicated pretty printer.  And I have a question: is JSON with metadata still JSON?

Comment: This answer has its merits, when `jq` is not available, but `python` is.

Answer (score 2):

Windows' `cmd` capabilities are very limited and support for JSON certainly isn't one of them, so I would advice against creating a batch-script! I would highly recommend the command-line tool [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) though. It prettifies by default.

**Stdin:**

```
ECHO {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3} | xidel -se "$json"
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

(If the input is JSON, `xidel` will parse and assign it to the (internal) global variable `$json`)

**File/url:**

```
xidel -s "input.json" -e "$json"
#or
xidel -s "https://[...]" -e "$json"
#or
xidel -se "json-doc('file-or-url')"
```

**Write to file:**

```
xidel -s "input.json" -e "$json" > output.json
#or
xidel -s "input.json" -e "file:write('output.json',$json,{'method':'json','indent':true()})"
#or
xidel -se "file:write('output.json',json-doc('input.json'),{'method':'json','indent':true()})"
```

**Process multiple files:**

```
FOR %A IN (*.json) DO @xidel -s %A -e "$json" > %~nA_pretty.json
```

While this would work for lots of JSON-files in a directory, it's also ***extremely*** slow, because `xidel` is called for each and every JSON-file.
`xidel` can do this much more efficiently with the integrated [EXPath File Module](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#modulefile).

```
xidel -se "file:list(.,false,'json')"
```

This returns a bare list of all JSON-files in the current directory.
(Equivalent of `DIR *.json /B`  and `FOR %A IN (*.json) DO @ECHO %A`)

```
xidel -se "file:list(.,false,'json') ! file:read-text(.)"
#or
xidel -se "for $x in file:list(.,false,'json') return file:read-text($x)"
```

Both commands return the content of each JSON-file in the current directory.
(Equivalent of `FOR %A IN (*.json) DO @TYPE %A`)

```
xidel -se "file:list(.,false,'json') ! json-doc(.)"
#or
xidel -se "for $x in file:list(.,false,'json') return json-doc($x)"
```

Both commands return the prettified parsed JSON content of each JSON-file in the current directory.
(Equivalent of `FOR %A IN (*.json) DO @xidel -s %A -e "$json"`, but ***much*** faster!)

```
xidel -se "file:list(.,false,'json') ! file:write(substring-before(.,'.json')||'_pretty.json',json-doc(.),{'method':'json','indent':true()})"
#or
xidel -se "for $x in file:list(.,false,'json') return file:write(substring-before($x,'.json')||'_pretty.json',json-doc($x),{'method':'json','indent':true()})"
```

Both commands write the prettified parsed JSON content of each JSON-file in the current directory to a new file with a filename which ends with "_pretty".

The final command prettified (with the necessary escape-characters):

```
xidel -se ^"^
  for $x in file:list(.,false,'json') return^
  file:write(^
    substring-before($x,'.json')^|^|'_pretty.json',^
    json-doc($x),^
    {'method':'json','indent':true()}^
  )^
"
```

Please download a `xidel` binary from the recommended ["Development"-branch](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/) to use these queries (and `json-doc()` in particular).
If you insist on using `xidel 0.9.8`, then use `json(file:read-text($x))` instead of `json-doc($x)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of [dnafication](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6068959/dnafication)'s [`python`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44492239/1529709) - if you have `perl`, you can do:

```
TYPE dirt.json | perl -MJSON -0ne "print JSON->new->pretty->encode(decode_json $_)"
```

This works with any `perl` newer than 5.14 (released 2011-05-14), because `JSON::PP` is a core module since then. Note that this is a pure-perl implementation, which does not perform as well as e.g. `JSON::XS`. [Read this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591444/which-perl-module-would-you-recommend-for-json-manipulation).