# Keep the string after the second occurrence of another string

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains lines that look like this:

```
username1
username2
./2011-05-25-0.json.gz:{"repo":{"url":"https://api.github.dev/repos//","name":"/"},"type":"FollowEvent","public":true,"created_at":"2011-05-25","payload":{"target":{"gravatar_id":"5e17","id":144929,"repos":12,"followers":1,"login":"username3"}},"actor":{"gravatar_id":"dec","id":21,"url":"https://api.github.dev/users/user","avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/decc?d=http://github.dev%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-user-420.png","login":"username4"},"id":"14"} 
./2011-05-25-0.json.gz:{"repo":{"url":"https://api.github.dev/repos//","name":"/"},"type":"FollowEvent","public":true,"created_at":"2011-05-25","payload":{"target":{"gravatar_id":"f9ed","id":82,"repos":5,"followers":4,"login":"username5"}},"actor":{"gravatar_id":"decc93","id":21,"url":"https://api.github.dev/users/username","avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/de?d=http://github.dev.user-420.png","login":"username6"},"id":"147"}
```

I would like to obtain a file that contains:

```
username1
username2
username4
username6
```

That is, if the string `"login":` occurs on a line, then obtain the string contained in `"` immediately after the second occurrence of `"login"`. Otherwise, keep the line untouched.

How can I do this with `grep`, or `sed`?

Comment: Maybe use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

Comment: Can't, because I can't install jq.

Comment: Can you use perl?

Comment: [Perl JSON module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591577/26428). [Python JSON lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really prefer an answer using grep or sed if possible - I can't seem to install things.

Comment: Is perl installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
sed 's/.*{.*login":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/g' text.txt
```

Or

```
sed -i.bkup 's/.*{.*login":"\([^"]*\)"}.*/\1/g' text.txt
```

To overwrite the file with the new usernames and bkup the old one to text.txt.bkup

NOTE: This assumes the username does not contain the pattern described by the regex.